# lxml truncates text that contains 'less than' character

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml

```
>>> s = '<div> < 20 </div>'
>>> import lxml.html
>>> tree = lxml.html.fromstring(s)
>>> lxml.etree.tostring(tree)
'<div> </div>'
```

Does anybody know any workaround for this?

Comment: This is broken html, but it's a pity that lxml can't handle it gracefully. This type of html is very common in the wild.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your HTML input is broken; that `<` left angle bracket should have been encoded to `&lt;` instead. From the [`lxml` documentation](http://lxml.de/parsing.html) on parsing broken HTML:

> The support for parsing broken HTML depends entirely on libxml2's recovery algorithm. It is not the fault of lxml if you find documents that are so heavily broken that the parser cannot handle them. There is also no guarantee that the resulting tree will contain all data from the original document. The parser may have to drop seriously broken parts when struggling to keep parsing. Especially misplaced meta tags can suffer from this, which may lead to encoding problems.

In other words, you take what you can get from such documents, the way `lxml` handles broken HTML is not otherwise configurable.

One thing you *could* try is to use a *different* HTML parser. Try [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) instead, it's broken HTML handling may be able to give you a different version of that document that does give you what you want out of it. BeautifulSoup can re-use different parser backends, including `lxml` and `html5lib`, so it'll give you more flexibility.

The `html5lib` parser does give you the `<` character (converted to a `&lt;` escape):

```
>>> BeautifulSoup("<div> < 20 </div>", "html5lib")
<html><head></head><body><div> &lt; 20 </div></body></html>
```

Comment: ugh, haven't done much html stuff for a while, forgot about that semicolon on the end of `&lt;` :)

Comment: Your answer is great. Your suggestion on using BS with html5lib solves the problem. Thank you. For those who downvote - I think they don't understand the problem.

Comment: Since you're already using `lxml`, it's worth pointing out that it has an [html5parser](http://lxml.de/html5parser.html) that follows the w3c's recommended parsing methods (which are theoretically what your browser uses).

Answer (score 1):

Your `<` should actually be `&lt;`, since `<` is sorta like a 'reserved character' in html. Then it should work.

Comment: What you want is not of any particular interest here. Your markup is not well-formed. No XML parser has to guess about fixing trash markup. So fix your markup *first*

Comment: Your negative tone is irrelevant. I'm scraping 3rd-part html page and need to parse it as it is. Example which I gave is only to demonstrate the issue.