# Python BeautifulSoup - Prevent Specific Fuzzy/Corrupt Tag Matching

Tags: python, html, parsing, tags, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python 2.7.2 & BeautifulSoup (bs4) 4.1.0.
I'm having a problem getting an item of interest from a page's html.
My instincts tell me the issue is that there is a "fuzzy" tag matching going on where it's treating text as a malformed tag.

Here is a simplified snippet to illustrate my problem:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = "<span>Age 4, Pet Dog, Weight < 6 lbs (< 3 kgs)</span>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print soup.get_text()
# prints: "Age 4, Pet Dog, Weight"

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print soup2.get_text()
# prints "Age 4, Pet Dog, Weight < 6 lbs (< 3 kgs)"
```

The stricter `html.parser` gives me the text I'm interested in; however, the site randomly spits out corrupt html. These pages with malformed html causes an `HTMLParser.HTMLParseError`. Is there a way to get the full line I'm interested in using the `lxml` parser or is that information lost? If that information is lost is there an alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of [lxml truncates text that contains 'less than' character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171035/lxml-truncates-text-that-contains-less-than-character)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the possible duplicate Max Worg linked, I came to the conclusion that the input text has to be "cleaned" before it is sent to BeautifulSoup. The less than character `<` is a reserved character in html and should be escaped to `&lt;` if it is used in text.

I wrote a function `escape_lt()` that exploits the fact that every `<` that I want to escape has a space character after it and all other html tags have no space after.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def escape_lt(html):
    html_list = list(html)
    for index in xrange(0, len(html) - 1):
        if html_list[index] == '<' and html_list[index + 1] == ' ':
            html_list[index] = '&lt;'
    return ''.join(html_list)

html = '<span>Age 4, Pet Dog, Weight < 6 lbs (< 3 kgs)</span>'
clean_html = escape_lt(html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(clean_html, 'lxml')
print soup.get_text()
# prints: Age 4, Pet Dog, Weight < 6 lbs (< 3 kgs)
```