# Scrapy - Scraping Websites With 'Less Than' Signs In Text

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy, html-parsing

Update:

This is a sample line of html, copied directly with 'copy outer html' in Chrome. I have added spaces before td and /td to show the actual html without triggering html in this post:

```
<td class="elem">3Fb1&lt;+1Lo&lt;+3Sb1</td>
```

Using scrapy shell, I run this command:

```
response.xpath('//table[@class="elm"][1]//td[@class="elem"]//text()')
```

The data from the response is:

```
3Fb1
```

But it should be

```
3Fb1<+1Lo<+3Sb1
```

I believe that the selector is stopping at the first tick (the '<') because it appears to be the beginning of a new html tag (or, I guess technically, the end of the text for the td tag).  On closer inspection, it does appear the coding used < instead of the '<' character.  I would expect that there is a simple qualifier I could add to my xpath request to ignore these, but after a week (during my few available hours) of googling and reading, I cannot find anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

I am new to scrapy and I have been working on a project (personal, for my kids) to gather a large amount of statistical data related to figure skating scoring.  The scoring stats extensively use '<' and '<<' to denote scoring details  (skaters call these 'ticks', which I will use to refer to them).

Scores are reported in tables, the table class of "ele" and a table numbered according to placement, then contain the executed skating elements and scores in rows.

An example scoring entry (cell in table) could be: `2A<`

Which has underlying code of: `<td class="elem">2A&lt;</td>`

Or this: `2A+1Lo<+2F`

Which has the underlying coding of:

```
<td class="elem">2A+1Lo&lt;+2F</td>
```

I have defined the object (may not be the correct term) row to iterate thru and then use this to get the specific cell (the second cell is always the element executed):

```
elements['executed_element'] = row.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract()
```

When the tick occur at the end of the text (like first example), I get everything, but when it is in the middle of the text (second example) it truncates everything after it.

I would go back and fix by hand, but I am pulling a couple million data points, so it is not practical to do so.

Any help for this newbie would be appreciated.

Sample page for scraping: http://www.usfigureskating.org/leaderboard/results/2018/25073/SEGM001.html

Code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    event = response.xpath('//title//text()').extract()
    category_segment = response.xpath('//h2[@class="catseg"]//text()').extract()
    skater_number = 1
    for row in response.xpath('//table[@class="sum"]/tbody/tr[not(contains(@class,"thead"))]'):
        skater_name = row.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract_first()
        skater_place = row.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract_first()
        skater_deductions = row.xpath('td[7]//text()').extract_first()
        # capture elements detail 
        skater_table = skater_place
        elements_id = 1
        element_table = '//table[@class="elm"][' + str(skater_table) +']/tbody/tr[not(contains(@class,"thead"))]'
        for row in response.xpath(element_table):
            elements = {}
            elements['Event'] = event 
            elements['Category_Segment'] = category_segment
            elements['skater_name'] = skater_name 
            elements['elements_id'] = elements_id
            elements['element_number'] = row.xpath('td[@class="num"]//text()').extract()
            elements['executed_element'] = row.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract()
            elements['element_info'] = row.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract()
            elements['base_value'] = row.xpath('td[4]//text()').extract()
            elements['bonus'] = row.xpath('td[5]//text()').extract()
            elements['GOE'] = row.xpath('td[6]//text()').extract()
            goe_table = str('.//td[@class="jud"]')
            judge_pointer = 8
            judge_number = 1
            elements_id += 1
            for cell in row.xpath(goe_table):
                elements['Judge Number'] = judge_number
                elements['Judge_GOE_Score'] = row.xpath('td[' + str(judge_pointer) + ']//text()').extract()
                yield elements
                judge_pointer += 1
                judge_number += 1
```

Comment: better show url to this page and your code so we could test it.

Comment: typical page: http://www.usfigureskating.org/leaderboard/results/2018/25073/SEGM001.html

Comment: My code section (as much as would fit)

        skater_number = 1
        for row in response.xpath('//table[@class="sum"]/tbody/tr[not(contains(@class,"thead"))]'):
            elements_id = 1
            element_table = '//table[@class="elm"][' + str(skater_table) +']/tbody/tr[not(contains(@class,"thead"))]'
            for row in response.xpath(element_table):
                elements = {}
                elements['element_number'] = row.xpath('td[@class="num"]//text()').extract()
                elements['executed_element'] = row.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract()

Comment: put code in question. it will be more readable.

Comment: and url you can add to question too. You should add url and code when you created question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your page with program `wget`and checked it in text editor - it doesn't use `&lt;` for `<` so scrapy has problems - but only with `<<+` and `<+`

I replaced `<<+` with `&lt&lt+` and `<+` with `&lt+`

```
body = response.body.replace(b'<<+', b'&lt;&lt;+').replace(b'<+', b'&lt;+')
```

And then I create selector

```
selector = scrapy.Selector(text=body.decode('utf-8'))
```

which I can use with `css()` and it gives me correct results

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    start_urls = ['http://www.usfigureskating.org/leaderboard/results/2018/25073/SEGM001.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        body = response.body.replace(b'<<+', b'&lt;&lt;+').replace(b'<+', b'&lt;+')

        selector = scrapy.Selector(text=body.decode('utf-8'))

        i = 1
        for x  in selector.css('.elem::text').extract():
            if 'Elements' in x:
                print('---', i, '---')
                i += 1
            else:
                print(x)

# --- it runs without project and saves in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

    # save in CSV or JSON
    #'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # 'json
    #'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', # 'output.json
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

Results:

```
Executed
--- 1 ---
2Ab1+2T
ChSt1
2Ab1
2Lz+1Lo+2Lo
2Lz
FSSp4
2F
CCoSp4
Executed
--- 2 ---
2Ab1
ChSt1
2Ab1+1Lo+2F
CCoSp2V
2Lz+2Lo
2Lo
2Lz
LSp4
Executed
--- 3 ---
CCoSp4
ChSt1
2Ab1+2Lo
2Lz+1Lo+2Lo
2Ab1
2Lz
2Fe
FSSp4
Executed
--- 4 ---
2Ab1+1Lo+2Lo
2Ab1
LSp4
ChSt1
2Lz
2F
2Lz+2T
CCoSp4
Executed
--- 5 ---
2Ab1
LSp2
ChSt1
2Ab1+1Lo+1Lo
2Lz+2Lo
2Lz
2F
CCoSp3
Executed
--- 6 ---
2Lz
1A
SSp3
ChSt1
2Lz+1Lo+2Lo
CCoSp3
2F+2Lo
2F
Executed
--- 7 ---
2F
2Ab1
CCoSp4
2Lz
2Ab1<+2T
ChSt1
2Lz+1Lo+2F
LSp4
Executed
--- 8 ---
1A
LSp4
ChSt1
2Lz
2Lz+2T
2Lo+2T+1Lo
2F
CCoSp4
Executed
--- 9 ---
2A<<
CCoSp4
ChSt1
2F+1Lo+2Lo
2Lze+2Lo
2Lze
2F
SSp4
Executed
--- 10 ---
2Lz
2Ab1
SSp3
ChSt1
2A<<+REP
2Lz+2Lo
2F
CCoSp4
Executed
--- 11 ---
FSSp4
2Ab1<+2Lo
ChSt1
2A<<
FCCoSp3
2F+2Lo<+1Lo<<
2Lz
2F
Executed
--- 12 ---
2A<<+1Lo+2Lo<
2Lze
SSp3
ChSt1
2A<<
2F
2F+2Lo<
CCoSp3
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you're experiencing is due to malformed HTML due to a reserved character (the less-than symbol `<`) in place of a `&lt;`.

One workaround to use BeautifulSoup with the `html5lib` parser backend on your `response` like this (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14171433/2314737)). By overwriting your response's body with the parsed content you should be able to use your current code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.http import TextResponse

# parse response body with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, "html5lib")
# overwrite response body
response = TextResponse(url="my HTML string", body=str(soup))

# from here on use your code
event = response.xpath('//title//text()').extract()
...
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a scrapy issue, but an `lxml` one. You can still use `scrapy` with this case, but with a different parser:

```
>> from scrapy import Selector

>> sel = Selector(text=response.body, type="xml")
>> sel.xpath('//table[@class="elm"][1]//td[@class="elem"]//text()') # should return it correctly
```

You'll have to use `sel` for extracting information from that page instead of `response`.

The known issue was already [reported here](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/issues/23)