# Web scraping of tables with R rvest, bottom right cell starting with "<=" is returned as logical NA

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape a web table which contains a cell starting with "<=". This cell (the bottom right cell) is returned as a logical NA. If I change "<=" into ">=", this value is scraped without issue. I have this issue with rvest 1.02 on RStudio Workbench, but no issue on my laptop version of RStudio running rvest 1.00.

```
# Minimal example: 
sample <- 
  minimal_html("<table>
               <tbody>
               <tr>
               <th>Col A</th><th>Col B</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
               <td>>=62.000</td><td><=72.000</td>
               </tr>
               </tbody>
               </table>")
sample %>% 
  rvest::html_elements("table") %>% 
  rvest::html_table()
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  `Col A`  `Col B`
  <chr>    <lgl>  
1 >=62.000 NA
```

Comment: I wonder if there is a failed attempt to fix html/fails because the < is interpreted as a bracket of a tag. Can you print `sample %>% toString()` and show the output?

Comment: Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171035/lxml-truncates-text-that-contains-less-than-character  where instead the < should have been entity encoded.  I suspect the html parser has been improved in rvest to handle this situ if that is the case.

Comment: @QHarr  I ran sample %>% toString and got the following error message: Error in as.character.xml_document(list(node = <pointer: (nil)>, doc = <pointer: (nil)>)) : external pointer is not valid

Comment: Can you do `sample %>% html_node('body') %>% toString()` ?

Comment: [1] "<body><table><tbody>\n<tr>\n<th>Col A</th>\n<th>Col B</th>\n               </tr>\n<tr>\n<td>&gt;=62.000</td>\n<td>\n               </td>\n</tr>\n</tbody></table></body>"

Comment: Yeah. You see how the parser has tried to fix the html and you have `<td>\n</td>`

Answer (score 0):

I have RStudio desktop (R 4.1.1) and rvest 1.0.2. I got the following result without issue:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  `Col A`  `Col B` 
  <chr>    <chr>   
1 >=62.000 <=72.000
```

Comment: Thanks! Same here with RStudio on my laptop. Edit: No issue also on RStudio Cloud. I'm lost :-(

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a set-up where the "<" is being interpreted as the start of a tag and thus the sequence `<td><` is interpreted as faulty html and cleaned rather than the "<" being preserved through html entity encoding as `&lt;`.

This would be an issue with the underlying parser, presumably later fixed.

Your set-up printing `sample %>% html_node('body') %>% toString()` resulting in

```html
<tr>
  \n
  <td>&gt;=62.000</td>
  \n
  <td>\n</td>
  \n
</tr>
```

seems to at least align with this reasoning.

I went looking for evidence and came across the following, for the 'lxml' html parser, [lxml truncates text that contains 'less than' character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171035/lxml-truncates-text-that-contains-less-than-character),  which seems to align with my supposition